# Backbone custom event callback arguments

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm attempting to pass an argument called newIndex in a custom event from one view to another using the `trigger()` function.  Here's an excerpt from the first view:

```
var ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#products',

    events:{
            sortupdate: function(event, ui){
                    ui.item.trigger('moved', ui.item.index());
            }
    }
});
```

The element on which the 'moved' event is being triggered is another view.  Here's an excerpt from that view:

```
var ProductItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
            moved: 'viewMoved'
    },

    initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'viewMoved');
    },

    viewMoved: function(newIndex){
            anotherFunc(this.model, newIndex);
    },

});
```

The issue I'm having is that in the `anotherFunc()` call, the newIndex argument appears to be the event itself rather than the value that I passed in when I triggered the event.  If I adjust the `viewMoved` callback to the following, it works correctly:

```
viewMoved: function(event, newIndex){
    anotherFunc(this.model, newIndex);
},
```

Is this intended functionality?  Is the event itself always the first argument passed to a custom event's callback, or is something else going on here?  If it's intended is this documented somewhere?  I was unable to find any reference to this in the Backbone documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone uses jQuery heavily under the hood, and your `ui.item` is actually a jQuery object. See the documentation for the [trigger function](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

In summary, you're using jQuery's `trigger` because `ui.item` is not a Backbone View. Extra parameters are always passed after the `event` object.